# Pre-created Stream and "using" block

Tags: c#, stream, clone

I'm really annoyed when "using" block tampered my pre-created object. I have this piece of code

```
class Asset {
    public Stream FileStream { get; set; }

    public Asset(string fileName) {
        FileStream = ...open a file stream...;
    }
}

// Somewhere else
Asset asset = new Asset("file.txt");
using (var reader = new StreamReader(asset.FileStream)) {
    //blah blah blah
}

// Somewhere else else
using (var reader2 = new StreamReader(asset.FileStream))
```

=> throws this exception:

> System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable.

Debugging step-by-step in Visual Studio helped me know that asset.FileStream has been disposed after the first "using" block.

Please help me to save his life :(( 
How can I create a clone stream from a stream?

Comment: I think the simple answer is don't dispose the stream before you are through with it... when you use a using block it will Dispose the Reader and in turn Dispose the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the fact that readers close the underlying stream is dumb.  The approach outlined in [this article](http://ydie22.blogspot.com/2008/02/about-idisposable-close-streams-and.html) is to create a decorator class that wraps the `Stream` and has a no-op for the `Close` and `Dispose` methods.  It's probably not worth the overhead, though, so you should consider just not using `using` for these readers.

Comment: Or, if the two using blocks are in the same method, you could move the second inside the first.